# Cursor position GetCursorPos() in C++ returns linking error

Tags: visual-c++, linker, cursor, c++-cli

Trying to get this to work
Using VisualStudio VC++ I'm trying to detect the cursor's position, take both x and y and use it for stuff, but no matter what - linking errors occur.

```
public: System::Void pictureDrag_MouseDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {
            POINT coord;
            GetCursorPos(&coord);
            int xx = coord.x, yy = coord.y;
            pictureBox2->Location = Drawing::Point(xx, yy); 
        }
```

Gets me these two linking errors

```
Stuff.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000011) "extern "C" int __stdcall GetCursorPos(struct tagPOINT *)" (?GetCursorPos@@$$J14YGHPAUtagPOINT@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall Stuff::Form1::pictureDrag_MouseDown(class System::Object ^,class System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs ^)" (?pictureDrag_MouseDown@Form1@Stuff@@$$FQ$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVMouseEventArgs@Forms@Windows@4@@Z)
Stuff.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __stdcall GetCursorPos(struct tagPOINT *)" (?GetCursorPos@@$$J14YGHPAUtagPOINT@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __clrcall Stuff::Form1::pictureDrag_MouseDown(class System::Object ^,class System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs ^)" (?pictureDrag_MouseDown@Form1@Stuff@@$$FQ$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVMouseEventArgs@Forms@Windows@4@@Z)
```

Please note, that there is a 
    #include 
at the beginning and I also tried to include the user32.lib to the project, did no result at all. The code itself is to damn simple to miss something big, this looks like I've forgotten to include something, but just cant figure out what. I'm new at C++ and we are so breaking up soon! As soon as I figure this one out.

Searched the world for help, cant stand any more. Please, help an idiot!

Comment: If it helps, a C++/CLI project with just `#include <windows.h> int main() {POINT p; GetCursorPos(&p);}` gives me linker errors, but adding `#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")` below the include links it all properly. I reckon you didn't add the library to the project properly. If that's it, I'd say it makes a pretty good dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739952/c-cli-linker-gives-unresolved-token-for-win32-function).

Comment: I've figured out there is something wrong with the import, but what. This helped, despite a new error `Debug\ChristmasTree.exe.intermediate.manifest : general error c1010070: Failed to load and parse the manifest.` Looks like the import's still somehow wrong, but it's a big progress ---- Forget about that, had an extra (and wrong) import in the manifest, removed and HAPPY! Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0):

> The code itself is to damn simple to miss something big

The function declaration is in header file, but the body of that function (definition) was build seperate (in lib file or dll file). In order to work, your project also need to include some lib file, which the function require.
In this case, the GetCursorPos() function and other functions from WinUser.h (which already include in Windows.h) require user32.lib to be work.

Normaly, all the important stuff, like all thing related to Windows, had been include by default. If some how it won't (by mess up with the project properties or anything else), you would have to manualy do that.

This can be achieve by simply put **#pragma comment(lib, "*lib name*")** right after using #include, replace the *lib name* with correct name of the lib file you want. In this case,  **#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")** like Chris had mention above.

Or if you using Visual Studio, right click on your project -> select "Properties" option at end of the list.

[image]

[image]

remember to chose the correct Configuration and Platform your project used.
Then in the Configuration tab, nagavite to Linker -> input. By default, it should had include all the important stuff in the Additional Dependencies like this:

[image]

If it is not, left click the fied -> click on the arrow. if it show "inherit from parent or project defaults" in the list, select that and apply, it should include all the stuff for you:

[image]

Or select edit, and type name of the lib you want in the white field, seperate by backspace like this:

[image]

Or tick on the check box and it will include all the stuff in the inherited values field for you. Then hit Ok -> Apply.